# free(): double free detected in tcache 2 signal aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c

im new here, firstable, thank you in advance for any suggestions or solutions to this problem.
I try to execute the following code in Code::blocks and in CLion and I get these errors. Those IDEs are installed in a Lenovo Yoga 700 with a Ubuntu 21.10. (I get the errors there)

I already execute the code in a Laptop with Windows 10 and it works without errors. Should I maybe make any extra configuarion in Unbuntu? or why does it happens?

This is my Code:

```
 //* LISTAS LIGADAS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tNodo{
    int valor;
    struct tNodo* sig;
}Nodo;

 typedef struct tList{
     int tamano;
     Nodo* primerItem;
     Nodo* ultimoItem;
 }ListaLigada;

 Nodo* getNode(int valor){
     Nodo* nodo = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
     nodo->valor= valor;
     nodo->sig = NULL;
     return nodo;
 }

 ListaLigada* obtenerNuevaListaLigada(){
     ListaLigada* ll = (ListaLigada*)malloc(sizeof(ListaLigada));
     ll->tamano=0;
     ll->primerItem = NULL;
     ll->ultimoItem = NULL;
     return ll;
 }

 //* Operaciones CRUD

 void add(ListaLigada* ll,Nodo* nodo){
    if (ll->primerItem == NULL) ll->primerItem = nodo;
    else ll->ultimoItem->sig = nodo;
    ll->ultimoItem = nodo;
    ll->tamano++;
 }

 Nodo* read(ListaLigada* ll, unsigned int indice){
    if (ll->tamano && indice<ll->tamano){
        Nodo* exploradorLista = ll->primerItem;
        int i = 0;
        while (i++ < indice)
            exploradorLista = exploradorLista->sig;
        return exploradorLista;
    }
 }

 void update(ListaLigada* ll, unsigned int indice, int nuevoValor){
     if (ll->tamano && indice<ll->tamano){
         Nodo* exploradorLista = ll->primerItem;
         int i = 0;
         while (i++ < indice)
             exploradorLista = exploradorLista->sig;
         exploradorLista->valor = nuevoValor;
     }
 }

void removed(ListaLigada* ll, unsigned int indice){
     if (ll->tamano && indice<ll->tamano){
         Nodo* aux;
         if (indice == 0){
             aux = ll->primerItem;
             ll->primerItem = ll->primerItem->sig;
             free(aux);
         } else {
             Nodo* exploradorLista = ll->primerItem;
             int i = 0;
             while (i++ < indice-1)
                 exploradorLista = exploradorLista->sig;
             aux = exploradorLista->sig;
             if (indice == ll->tamano-1){
                 exploradorLista->sig = NULL;
                 ll->ultimoItem = exploradorLista;
             } else exploradorLista->sig = exploradorLista->sig->sig;
         }
         free(aux);
         ll->tamano--;
     }
 }


 int main(){

     ListaLigada* LISTA = obtenerNuevaListaLigada();
     Nodo* a = getNode(1);
     Nodo* b = getNode(2);
     Nodo* c = getNode(3);
     Nodo* d = getNode(4);

     add(LISTA,a);
     add(LISTA,b);
     add(LISTA,c);
     add(LISTA,d);

     printf("%d\n",read(LISTA,3)->valor);
     update(LISTA,3,11);
     printf("%d\n",read(LISTA,3)->valor);
     printf("%d",read(LISTA,0)->valor);
     removed(LISTA,0);
     printf("\n%d",read(LISTA,0)->valor);

     free(LISTA);
     return 0;
 }
```

[Error in Code::blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehw5O.png)

[Error in CLion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5Ycd.png)

Comment: After searching for `free` in your source it took me 5 seconds to find `if (indice == 0){` ... `free(aux); } ... free(aux);`. You need to fix this bug.

Comment: The title of your question says 'double free', then in your code, you are calling `free(aux)` twice. What more do you need?

Comment: Thank you guys, Im learning C, sorry and thanks for your patience. It works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `remove`, in case that `indice == 0`, the `free` is executed 2 times.

```
if (indice == 0) {
  aux = ...
  ll->primerItem = ...
  free(aux);            <<< Cut this call
} else {
  ...
}
free(aux);
```